# RenderPartial a view from another controller (and in another folder)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, renderpartial

I two database entities that i need to represent and i need to output them in a single page.

I have something like this

Views
  Def
    ViewA
    ViewB
  Test
    ViewC

I want to ViewC to display ViewA, which displays ViewB.

Right now i'm using something like this:

```
// View C
<!-- bla -->
<% Html.RenderPartial(Url.Content("../Definition/DefinitionDetails"), i); %>


// View A
<!-- bla -->
<% Html.RenderPartial(Url.Content("../Definition/DefinitionEditActions")); %>
```

Is there a better to do this? I find that linking with relative pathnames can burn you.
Any tips?

Any chance I can make somehtiing like...

Html.RenderPartial("Definition","DefinitionDetails",i); ?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 48, accepted):

this is works for me!

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/NewsFeeds/NewsFeedPartial.cshtml")
```

Comment: why when it is on other controller folder its necesary put *.cshtml?

Answer (score 35):

You can refer to Views with full paths, like:

```
Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Definition/DefinitionDetails")
```

Even better, use the [T4MVC library](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC), which does the above and makes it (quasi-) strongly-typed. You can refer to any view from any controller or view. You use it like this:

```
Html.RenderPartial(MVC.Definition.Views.DefinitionDetails)
```

or

```
Html.RenderPartial(MVC.Definition.Views.DefinitionDetails, myModel)
```

Comment: I've found that you have to add the '.ascx' to the end of the path with the first method. (This might just be for a particular project setup)

Comment: Just to specify, we're talking about the `Html.RenderPartial` overload in `System.Web.Mvc.Html.RenderPartialExtenstions` not `MvcContrib.UI.InputBuilder.Views.HtmlExtensions` nor `Microsoft.Web.Mvc.Html.HtmlHelperExtensions`. Sometimes Resharper gives you too many choices.

Comment: Yes I tried the first method will produce error, it supposed to have the file extension. So it should be `Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Controller/Action.ext")` where ext can be aspx, ascx, cshtml or vbhtml.

Comment: This answer is not quiet right. If you supply a path you need to supply the extension as well. if you do not supply a path you must NOT supply an extension. Details answer added below to clarify the options.

Comment: Yes @CallMeLaNN you are right first method gives an error "The partial view '~/Views/Definition/DefinitionDetails' was not found"  and it can be removed by adding ext at the end

Answer (score 14):

Just to clarify which options work exactly:

### 1) The extension of the view file *is* required *if you supply a path*.

### 2) If you do not supply a path, do not supply the extension.

The examples below assume cshtml files.

### Use `RenderPartial` in a code block:

```
// This looks in default view folder, then shared, checking for .aspx, .cshtml etc
Html.RenderPartial("DefinitionDetails"); 

// This looks in specified path and requires the extension
Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Definition/DefinitionDetails.cshtml");
```

### Use `Partial` for inline Razor syntax:

```
// This looks in default view folder, then shared, checking for .aspx, .cshtml etc
@Html.Partial("DefinitionDetails")

// This looks in specified path and requires the extension
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Definition/DefinitionDetails.cshtml")
```

Note: *Apparently `RenderPartial` is slightly faster than `Partial`*, but I also expect fully pathed names will be a faster than letting MVC search for the file.

If you are producing partials in a loop (i.e. from a collection in your view model), it is likely you will need to pass through specific viewmodels:

### e.g.

```
   @foreach (var group in orderedGroups)
   {
       Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/ControllerName/ViewName.cshtml", group);
   }
```

I just had to do all this on a project and found the marked answer a little misleading.

Comment: Can I use Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Definition/DefinitionDetails.cshtml", model) in action method to generate string?

Comment: @HimalayaGarg It is just a function. You can use any function that returns a string the same way :)

Answer (score 1):

Could you not copy the partials into the shared folder then just do:

`<% Html.RenderPartial("DefinitionDetails", i); %>` and

`<% Html.RenderPartial("DefinitionEditActions"); %>`

Comment: Seeing as you want to access the view from multiple controllers I would say so.