# calling partial view from another controller inside @Html.RenderPartial

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview, html.renderpartial

The directory structure is:

```
controllers -> HomeController, TableController                            
views -> home -> index.cshtml                                  
views -> Table -> Navigate.cshtml
```

The index.cshtml corresponds to the index method in the HomeController
the navigate.cshtml is a partial view and corresponds to the Navigate method in the TableController. The navigate method's return type is `PartialViewResult` and returns:

```
PartialView("Navigate", Data);
```

The Index.cshtml has `@Html.RenderPartial()`...

if I wanted to call the partial view from the TableController, could I just say:

```
@Html.RenderPartial("~/Controllers/Table/Navigate");
```

So it renders the partial view returned by navigate method in the TableController.

Comment: So.......................

Comment: Yes, you can call the partial view from the Table view. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879733/renderpartial-a-view-from-another-controller-and-in-another-folder

Answer (score 3):

IF all you want to do is to include the partial view. Why not call it using action method. Like:

```
@Html.Action("Navigate","Table")
```

You can place this anywhere and it should work.